# urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused> when trying to containerize Frontend

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to containerize a full stack application with Docker. The backend (provider) provides its information in JSON-Format in Java. The frontend (consumer) should be able to read to information and is based on Python.

So, in my app.py, I have my code including the ProviderURL. The code uses this variable to get access to the data of the backend. In my case, I don't know if I set it right:

`jokeProviderUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"`

The Dockerfile of this frontend is:

```
FROM python:3.8.5-alpine

WORKDIR /M347_LB02_JokeConsumerPython

COPY . .

RUN apk add --no-cache python3-dev \
    && pip install --upgrade pip
    
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

The Dockerfile of the backend is:

```
FROM maven:latest
 
WORKDIR /M347_LB02_JokeProviderJava
 
COPY . .
 
RUN mvn clean install

CMD ["mvn", "spring-boot:run"]
```

When I run the docker-compose, I can open the port of the backend and see the data. Furthermore, I can't reach out to the port of the frontend. Why is this?

The docker-compose.yml-File:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build: M347_LB02_JokeProviderJava/.
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  frontend: 
    build: M347_LB02_JokeConsumerPython/.
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
```

Comment: The `frontend` container is a server component that does an HTTP GET to `backend`, renders the results, and returns HTTP to the browser; it doesn't itself run or serve browser Javascript code?  It should use the other container's Compose service name `backend` in the URL, since `localhost` in Docker generally means "the current container".  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Comment: I've tried it with http://backend:8080 too but this didn't work either for me

Answer (score 0):

You should use Docker network between services. The services can communicate via any port inside a Docker Network.

Your `docker-compose.ym` file with networking:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build: M347_LB02_JokeProviderJava/.
    # If you want to connect to backend from front-end then you don't need to open port because the services
    # can communicate via any port inside Docker network.
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - app_net

  frontend: 
    build: M347_LB02_JokeConsumerPython/.
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      - app_net

networks:
  app_net: {}
```

Then you can connect to backend service via service name:

```
jokeProviderUrl = "http://backend:8080"
```

Note:

- You can read more about "localhost" usage inside Docker, if you are interested what was problem with your localhost usage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/11502612 (The "localhost" doesn't mean the same [or not simply] as outside of docker)